# Change the label of a UITabBarItem from different View

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, uitextfield, uitabbaritem

**This is mainly a delegation question** because I'm still learning and don't get it. I don't know **how to go about creating the delegate I need**.

I have **a tabbed view controllerwith 2 views,** let's call them **view 1** and **view 2**. Then I have **a settings view which is not part of the tabbed navigation and accessible by both view 1 and 2**.

How do I go about changing the label of a `UITabBarItem` from the settings view with a text field. You can change a `UITabBarItem` by **setTitle**, but **I don't know how to set up the delegation.**

To give you perspective, View 1 and View 2 are actually Player 1 and Player 2. I want to give the user the option to change the PLayer 1 and PLayer 2 labels to their actual names via the settings screen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you viewing the Settings View . Is it pushed in the Navigation Controller or is it presented modally ? the  code for adding the Settings View would be helpful to help you

Comment: The settings View is presented modally. I created the transition using storyboard so I don't know where or if the code exists... I'm still extremely new to this.

I really just need to know how to have a text fiel in one view change stuff in a different view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code in the Settings View Controller (that is presented modally) and call it when you need to change the text field of one of the tabbaritems.

```
UITabBarController  *tabBarController =(UITabBarController *)[self presentingViewController];
NSArray *tabBarItems =[tabBarController.tabBar items];
UITabBarItem *barItem1=[tabBarItems objectAtIndex:0 ]; // or 1
barItem1.title=@"NewName";
```